# Argument Dependent Lookup and stream operators overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, argument-dependent-lookup

I have a library which expose some sort of container `struct` in which I want to collect diverse generic type of data which might be from the same `namespace` of the library as well as data from the `std` namespace such as `array` or `tuple` or `pairs`.

This container has a `print_all` method which will invoke `operator<<` for all the elements in the container. Such an operator is supposed to be provided by the user of the library.

Testing the library, I am using different template parameters for `T`, but I do not care too much about what is being printed by the `print_all` method. For the test purpose I care only that an example character is being printed no matter which `T` is being tested. Actually, I my real code I am using Google Test Framework and the behavior of the method under test is really asserted to be the same for every data type provided.

I tried to provide both a generic version of `operator<<` and two specific versions of it. You can see them in between the `#if` directive. None of the two compilation branches compiles correctly, most likely because of some violation of the König lookup rules. But anyway what I want to do should be easily possible somehow. What am I missing?

Here is the example code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace my
{
template<typename DataType>
struct Container
{
    void print_all( std::ostream& os ) const
    {
        std::for_each(std::begin(data),
                      std::end(data),
                      [&os](const DataType& value)
                      {
                          os << value;
                      });
    }

    std::vector<DataType> data;
};

namespace test
{
struct Data
{
    std::byte data[4];
};

using Array = std::array<std::byte,4>;

#if 0

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& data)
{
    return os << 'X';
}

#else

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Data& data)
{
    return os << 'X';
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Array& data)
{
    return os << 'X';
}

#endif

void run()
{  
    // Test with custom data
    { 
        Container< Data> container;
        container.data.resize(1);
        container.print_all( std::cout );
    }
    // Test with std data
    {
        Container< Array> container;
        container.data.resize(1);
        container.print_all( std::cout );
    }
}

} // namespace test
} // namespace my

int main()
{
    my::test::run();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `template<typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& data)` would conflict with just about *every* other `operator<<` function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude clear, but why also the two specific ones will not work? Is there a way to restrict the subset for which `T` is meant?

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 some smart `enable_if`

Comment: Since you don't show the errors you're getting it's hard to say. If you have build-error, please always include them inside the question itself, copy-pasted (as text) in full and complete.

Comment: Here is link to CE for all tinkerers: https://godbolt.org/z/iXz7nW

Comment: If I should hazard a guess, a major issue is because when the compiler is compiling the `print_data` function, it doesn't know anything about the `Data` or `Array` types, and definitely don't have any overloaded `<<` operators that can be used.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude btw isn't `using` just making "soft" alias to type, not triggering ADL to think this type is from his namespace?

Comment: @bartop Yes that's right, that won't work. Actually I should have remembered as I had a [very similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59770581/cant-use-overloaded-comparison-operator-with-catch-test) just a little while ago.

Comment: @bartop `enable_if` afaik works only if you mutually exclude functions, so that in the end only one can be valid for a type. But I have no control over those `operator<<` defined in `std` which would at that point always win as soon as I `template` my test version of them.

Comment: @bartop totally correct: I tried with the `using` directive but ADL just ignores it. And maybe it is actually better like this for C++ language as a whole, it would really break too many things, But yet I need then another solution for this specific problem I am facing, because my example is small, but the types `T` I need to test are many.

Answer (score 2):

ADL looks into the namespaces associates with the arguments.

```
using Array = std::array<std::byte,4>;
```

this type `test::Array` is an alias.  The namespaces associated with it for the purpose of ADL is `std`.  `test` is not associated with it.  ADL will only look in `std`.  You are not permitted to add operators to `std`; if you violate that, your program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.  ADL cannot help you, because it only helps people who own the namespace(s) associated with the arguments.

Any `<<` you want to support in `std` needs to be in `namespace my`, defined before your `print_all` function.

Your code for `Data` looks to me like it works, I assume your question was just poorly written, as it implies `os <<Data` does not work.  If I am wromg amd it doesn't work, it is because of some typo; ADL works fine on `struct`s, but not on aliases.  In the future, please include complete error messages when code doesn't work.

Comment: Problem is: how can I define an `operator<<` before `print_all`, and meanwhile allow the user of the library to use the whole thing with his own provided `T`? Does this mean that the user has to define `operator<<` before including the header files of `my` lib? Wouldn't that be kinda weird?

Comment: @nyarla if it is the users type, they can define it in the user:s namespace.  It does not have to be before `my`  If it is a std type, they cannot customize `<<`.

Comment: Actually in my example if I move the `operator<<` version for the `std::array` at global namespace just before the `main` function, it works. So they can indeed be overloaded.

Comment: @nyarl you czn add a second layer of ADL that permits custom dispatching.  `void my::print_all( my::print_tag_t, std::ostream& os, T const& t ){ os<<t; }`  Then the user can customize that.  Becauae it will be found.by ADL on `print_tag_t`  they can introduce their overload after they include your header. (In namespace `my`)

Comment: @nyar that is fragile, as << in my could block it from being seen